# C++ weird error strstr

Tags: c++

check the screenshot, i honestly have no idea what's wrong with it

can anyone help me?

```
        if (strstr(pMaterial->GetTextureGroupName(), "World textures"))
        {
            pMaterial->ColorModulate(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        }
```

[image: screenshot]

1: C2665 'strstr': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

2: E0304 no instance of overloaded function "strstr" matches the argument list

Comment: whats wrong with the screenshot is that it is a screenshot. Please include code and error in the question (not images and please no links to images)

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong. You're passing in `std::string, const char[15]`, and there is no overloaded version of `strstr` that accepts those parameters.

Comment: Did you even read the error? If yes, you would know exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Consider using [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead `strstr`.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious - as in "write C++, not C"? - Yes, I agree ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetTextureGroupName()` function is of a [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type. The [std::strstr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) function does not accept a `std::string` as a parameter. Use the string [c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function instead:

```
if (std::strstr(pMaterial->GetTextureGroupName().c_str(), "World textures")){
    pMaterial->ColorModulate(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}
```

Rather than falling back to C style strings you should explore the `std::string` facilities as pointed out in the comments. The modified example uses the [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) member function:

```
if (pMaterial->GetTextureGroupName().find("World textures")!= std::string::npos){
    pMaterial->ColorModulate(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Why degrade to a C string rather than using what `std::string` provides ?

Answer (score -1):

strstr accept two char * pointers. You could change it to:

```
strstr(pMaterial->GetTextureGroupName().c_str(), "World textures")
```

Comment: I think there is a typo: c_ptr -> c_str